# Storing files as list and reading data from them in python

Tags: python, list

I was wondering if I had a directory full of similar .txt files, if there was a way to store these as a list of lists in python, iterate through the list to open the files, and then iterate through the objects in the file to achieve something. For example:

```
ls /Path/to/directory/
1.txt 2.txt 3.txt 4.txt
```

the contents of each file would be like:

```
more 1.txt
1
2
3
4
```

For the python script something like:

```
import os
pathname = os.path.join("directory",filenames)
for i in pathname:
    file_open = open(pathname[i])
    for j in file_open:
        file_sum = sum(int[j])
    return file_sum
```

or would it just be better to do this with a shell script to run the python command for each file individually and write output to file? I just wanted to see if there was a cool pythonic way to do this.

```
#!/bin/bash

RUN_PATH=$1; shift
cd $RUN_PATH

for file in $RUN_PATH*
do
    MONEY=`basename $file`
    BAG=`python my_script.py $file`
    echo $MONEY "      " $BAG >> money_bag.txt
done;
```

thanks for the help

Comment: You want to sum up the integers in each file and store the output in a list?, so like `[10, sum_2, sum3, sum4]`?

Comment: Yes, it'd be better to do it all in Python. You can use `os` functions for working with files, but if you have a recent Python please check out the new `pathlib` module, it's much nicer. BTW, in Bash you should avoid using the backtick syntax for getting the output of commands, it's deprecated, prone to typos and being mis-read, and you can't nest it. Use the `$()` syntax instead.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks I will keep that in mind for pathlib and bash scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. We can use a combination of `glob` (to get all of the text files), a short function and a dictionary comprehension:

```
import glob


def sum_file(file_path):
    total = 0
    with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            try:
                total += int(line)
            except ValueError:
                continue
    return total


folder_location = r'path\to\directory\*.txt'

file_sums = {p: sum_file(p) 
             for p in glob.glob(folder_location)}
```

`file_sums` will be a dictionary where the keys are the paths to each file, and the values the total of all lines that can be interpreted as integers in those files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try in one line:

Assuming you have stored all files names in one list now and each file contain numbers like:

1.txt file:

```
1
2
3
4
```

You can try :

```
pathname = ['1.txt','2.txt','3.txt','4.txt']

print([sum([int(i) for i in open(i,'r+')]) for i in pathname])
```

output:

```
[10, 14, 26, 30]
```

Comment: Also, please close the file handles after using them and it will not be a one-line any longer.